# Freezing and Exporting a TensorFlow model in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to migrate existing code (using Estimators) written in Tensorflow 1.13 to Tensorflow 2.0, but I am having issues trying to find the equivalent APIs to freeze and output a graph and output a .pb file.

In tensorflow 1.13, the estimator class has a function export_savedmodel, which takes in a model path and an serving_input_receiver_fn. I am having trouble to set up serving_input_receiver_fn, since it seems that it takes in placeholders. However, when migrated to Tensorflow 2.0, although the same APIs exists, due to the eager execution model setting to default, placeholders doesn't work with eager execution mode.

```py
   def export(self):
        self.configure()
        a_shape = (None, None, None, self.IMG_CHANNELS)
        b_shape = tf.TensorShape((None, None, self.IMU_DATA_DIM))
        a = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, a_shape, name="a")
        b = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, b_shape, name='b')
        input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn({
            'a': a,
            'b':b
        })
        return self.modelPath, input_fn
```

RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution.

Therefore, I would like to ask, what is a proper way to freeze and export a model to output a .pb file, from existing checkpoint files?

Comment: Take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31055) where they called the model inside a function and exporting the function as a signature.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for `tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn()`.
It can be pasted directly into a notebook with TF2.x. Hope that helps.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

checkpoint_dir = "/some/location/to/store/the_model"

input_column = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x")
# Use a LinearClassifier but this would also work with a custom Estimator
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=[input_column])

# Create a fake dataset with only one feature 'x' and an associated label
def input_fn():
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        ({"x": [1., 2., 3., 4.]}, [1, 1, 0, 0])).repeat(200).shuffle(64).batch(16)
estimator.train(input_fn)

# The thing is that we must not call raw_input_fn: would result in the error 
# "tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution."
# Instead pass raw_input_fn directly to estimator.export_saved_model()

feature_to_tensor = {
    # pass some dummy tensor: this is just to get the shapes for the placeholder
    # that will be created by build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(). 
    # Adjust with the shape of 'x'.
    # 
    'x': tf.constant(0.),
}
raw_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_to_tensor, default_batch_size=None)
export_dir = estimator.export_saved_model(checkpoint_dir, raw_input_fn).decode()
```

You can then check the exported model:

```py
!saved_model_cli show --all --dir $export_dir

MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['predict']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['x'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1)
        name: Placeholder:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['all_class_ids'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT32
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: head/predictions/Tile:0
    outputs['all_classes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: head/predictions/Tile_1:0
    outputs['class_ids'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: head/predictions/ExpandDims:0
    outputs['classes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: head/predictions/str_classes:0
    outputs['logistic'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: head/predictions/logistic:0
    outputs['logits'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: linear/linear_model/linear/linear_model/linear/linear_model/weighted_sum:0
    outputs['probabilities'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 2)
        name: head/predictions/probabilities:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

The exported model can now be loaded and used for inference by another process:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
imported = tf.saved_model.load(export_dir)
f = imported.signatures["predict"]
f(x=tf.constant([-2., 5., -3.]))

{'class_ids': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=int64, numpy=
 array([[1],
        [0],
        [1]], dtype=int64)>,
 'classes': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 1), dtype=string, numpy=
 array([[b'1'],
        [b'0'],
        [b'1']], dtype=object)>,
 'all_class_ids': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
 array([[0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1]])>,
...etc...
```